# What starts new subshell in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, process

Are there actions in Bash other than pipes and command substitution that start a new subshell?

Comment: A new process, or a new subshell?

Comment: It seems that command substitution may not always start a new subshell. See [When does command substitution spawn more subshells than the same commands in isolation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21331042) for more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Putting a command chain in parens (`( ... )`) also starts a new subshell.

```
( cd /tmp ; pwd ) ; pwd
```

Answer (score 0):

Each shell script running is, in effect, a subprocess (child process) of the parent shell.

A shell script can itself launch subprocesses. These subshells let the script do parallel processing, in effect executing multiple subtasks simultaneously.

say you have script `test.sh`. After you run it if you run the command

```
ps -ef|grep -i test.sh
```

you will see the it runs with different PID

In general, an external command in a script forks off a subprocess/subshell

Comment: Subshells and subprocesses are not the same thing. `grep` in the right-hand side of your pipeline is started by a subshell. The left side is not. So if you were to do `cd .. | pwd`, you'd see the directory change. If you did `echo | cd ..; pwd`, you'd not. Also, `cd` is a shell builtin, so it is never a subprocess, but still in a subshell. A subprocess is a fork-exec. Subprocesses running in a subshell behave like a fork-fork-exec.