# When does command substitution spawn more subshells than the same commands in isolation?

Tags: bash, shell, optimization, subshell, command-substitution

Yesterday it was suggested to me that using command substitution in bash causes an unnecessary subshell to be spawned. The advice was specific to [this use case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21317997/313192):

```
# Extra subshell spawned
foo=$(command; echo $?)

# No extra subshell
command
foo=$?
```

As best I can figure this appears to be correct for this use case. However, a quick search trying to verify this leads to reams of confusing and contradictory advice. It seems popular wisdom says ALL usage of command substitution will spawn a subshell. For example:

> The command substitution expands to the output of commands. **These commands are executed in a subshell**, and their stdout data is what the substitution syntax expands to. ([source](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst))

This seems simple enough unless you keep digging, on which case you'll start finding references to suggestions that this is not the case.

> Command substitution **does not necessarily invoke a subshell**, and in most cases won't. The only thing it guarantees is out-of-order evaluation: it simply evaluates the expressions inside the substitution first, then evaluates the surrounding statement using the results of the substitution. ([source](https://github.com/grncdr/js-shell-parse/issues/1))

This seems reasonable, but is it true? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9109654/313192) to a subshell related question tipped me off that `man bash` has this to note:

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).

This brings me to the main question. **What, exactly, will cause command substitution to spawn a subshell that would not have been spawned anyway to execute the same commands in isolation?**

Please consider the following cases and explain which ones incur the overhead of an extra subshell:

```
# Case #1
command1
var=$(command1)

# Case #2
command1 | command2
var=$(command1 | command2)

# Case #3
command1 | command 2 ; var=$?
var=$(command1 | command2 ; echo $?)
```

Do each of these pairs incur the same number of subshells to execute? Is there a difference in POSIX vs. bash implementations? **Are there other cases where using command substitution would spawn a subshell where running the same set of commands in isolation would not?**

Comment: This question has some related info: [Command substitution vs process substitution](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15416570)

Comment: I don't think I would take your second quote as any kind of authoritative information about how `bash` is implemented. However, I would note that subshell != process; a subshell (in the sense of a new scope for variables) is not required to spawn a new process to run it. (This is the third point made in the accepted answer to your linked question.)

Comment: @chepner If I had taken that as authoritative I probably wouldn't be asking here. The point here is to get the issue de-mystified a bit in a peer reviewed environment. I realize what a subshell even is is probably something an answer will need to clarify on order to give a sensible explanation as to when "unnecessary" resources are being used.

Comment: The second quote's comment "There aren't any builtins that explicitly mean 'subshell';" is at best misleading and in my view flat-out wrong (and has caused me not to read the rest of the article). The `( ... )` explicitly creates a sub-shell; the commands within the parentheses must be executed in a sub-shell (meaning that any changes made to variables etc must not affect the main shell). That used to be done by forking and letting the child execute the contents of the sub-shell script while the parent waits for it to complete. A shell might avoid that if it has good enough scoping abilities.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler to be fair, if you read the exchange further down he recants, although in a somewhat obtuse way.

Comment: @kojiro: yes, he does, but because the posting leaves an ambiguous message, rather than being rewritten to present the final view unambiguously, or point to where the final view is presented unambiguously, it leaves the posting as 'of dubious merit' as a source of information.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/41315367/717267

Answer (score 17):

**Update and caveat**:

**This answer has a troubled past in that I confidently claimed things that turned out not to be true. I believe it has value in its *current* form, but please help me eliminate other inaccuracies (or convince me that it should be deleted altogether).**

I've **substantially revised - and mostly gutted - this answer** after @kojiro pointed out that my testing methods were flawed (I originally used `ps` to look for child processes, but that's too slow to always detect them); a new testing method is described below.

I originally claimed that not all bash subshells run in their own child process, but that turns out not to be true.

As @kojiro states in his answer, *some* shells - other than bash - DO sometimes avoid creation of child processes for subshells, so, *generally* speaking in the world of shells, one should not assume that a subshell implies a child process.

As for the OP's cases in **bash** (assumes that `command{n}` instances are *simple commands*):

```
# Case #1
command1         # NO subshell
var=$(command1)  # 1 subshell (command substitution)

# Case #2
command1 | command2         # 2 subshells (1 for each pipeline segment)
var=$(command1 | command2)  # 3 subshells: + 1 for command subst.

# Case #3
command1 | command2 ; var=$?         # 2 subshells (due to the pipeline)
var=$(command1 | command2 ; echo $?) # 3 subshells: + 1 for command subst.;
                                     #   note that the extra command doesn't add 
                                     #   one
```

It looks like using command substitution (`$(...)`) **always adds an extra subshell in bash** - as does enclosing any command in `(...)`.

**I believe, but am not certain these results are correct**; here's how I tested (bash 3.2.51 on OS X 10.9.1) - **please tell me if this approach is flawed**:

- Made sure only 2 interactive bash shells were running: one to run the commands, the other to monitor.
- In the 2nd shell I monitored the `fork()` calls in the 1st with `sudo dtruss -t fork -f -p {pidOfShell1}` (the `-f` is necessary to also trace `fork()` calls "transitively", i.e. to include those created by subshells themselves).
- Used only the builtin `:` (no-op) in the test commands (to avoid muddling the picture with additional `fork()` calls for external executables); specifically:

  - `:`
  - `$(:)`
  - `: | :`
  - `$(: | :)`
  - `: | :; :`
  - `$(: | :; :)`
- Only counted those `dtruss` output lines that contained a non-zero PID (as each child process also reports the `fork()` call that created it, but with PID 0).
- Subtracted 1 from the resulting number, as running even just a builtin from an interactive shell apparently involves at least 1 `fork()`.
- Finally, assumed that the resulting count represents the number of subshells created.

Below is what I still believe to be correct from my original post: when bash creates subshells.

---

**bash creates subshells in the following situations:**

- for an expression surrounded by parentheses ( `(...)` )

  - *except* directly inside `[[ ... ]]`, where parentheses are only used for logical grouping.

- for *every* segment of a pipeline (`|`), including the *first* one

  - Note that *every* subshell involved is a clone of the *original* shell in terms of *content* (process-wise, subshells can be forked from other subshells (*before* commands are executed)).
    Thus, modifications of subshells in earlier pipeline segments do not affect later ones.
    (By design, commands in a pipeline are launched *simultaneously* - sequencing only happens through their connected stdin/stdout pipes.)
  - `bash 4.2+` has shell option `lastpipe` (OFF by default), which causes the *last* pipeline segment NOT to run in a subshell.

- for command substitution (`$(...)`)
- for process substitution (`<(...)`)

  - typically creates *2* subshells; in the case of a *simple command*, [@konsolebox came up with a technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24655246/45375) to only create *1*: prepend the simple command with `exec` (`<(exec ...)`).

- background execution (`&`)

Combining these constructs will result in more than one subshell.

Comment: How did you test for the creating of a new process?

Comment: I don't think your results are valid, because ps isn't fast enough to capture some of those subshells you create above. For example, you say *an expression surrounded by parentheses does not run in a child process for simple commands*, but try continuously outputting `ps` while running `for i in {0..999999}; do ( : ); done`. You won't see every new process, but you'll see some, and the number of PIDs the system goes through increases rapidly.

Comment: @kojiro: Excellent catch, thanks. Not that it matters any longer, but how would you test in the absence of `$BASHPID`? I'll update my answer.

Comment: @mklement0 That's tough. My first attempts were on Mavericks (which still has Bash 3, sigh), and I ended up trying long loops with many tiny subshells in them. On Linux with Bash 3 you may be able to use /proc/self, but since OS X doesn't have /proc, Bash 3 doesn't have BASHPID, and `( sh -c 'echo $$PPID' )` violates some invariants of the question, I don't feel there's a clean solution.

Comment: @kojiro: Thanks; I've come up with something based on `sudo dtruss -t fork -f -p {pid}` on OSX; would you mind taking a look at the updated answer and tell me whether that looks sound?

Answer (score 9):

In Bash, a subshell always executes in a new process space. You can verify this fairly trivially in Bash 4, which has the `$BASHPID` and `$$` environment variables:

- $$ Expands  to  the  process ID of the shell.  In a () subshell, it expands to the process ID of the current  shell,  not  the  subshell.
- BASHPID Expands to the process id of the  current  bash  process.   This differs  from  $$ under certain circumstances, such as subshells that do not require bash to be re-initialized

in practice:

```
$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
$ echo $$-$BASHPID
4671-4671
$ ( echo $$-$BASHPID )
4671-4929
$ echo $( echo $$-$BASHPID )
4671-4930
$ echo $$-$BASHPID | { read; echo $REPLY:$$-$BASHPID; }
4671-5086:4671-5087
$ var=$(echo $$-$BASHPID ); echo $var
4671-5006
```

About the only case where the shell can elide an *extra* subshell is when you pipe to an explicit subshell:

```
$ echo $$-$BASHPID | ( read; echo $REPLY:$$-$BASHPID; )
4671-5118:4671-5119
```

Here, the subshell implied by the pipe is explicitly applied, but not duplicated.

This varies from some [other shells that try very hard to avoid `fork`-ing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686872/sub-shell-diffferences-between-bash-and-ksh). Therefore, while I feel the argument made in `js-shell-parse` misleading, it is true that not all shells always `fork` for all subshells.