# shell script iterate throw directories and split filenames

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I need to extract 2 things from filenames - the extension and a number.

I have a folder "/var/www/html/MyFolder/", this folder contains a few more folders and in each folder are some files stored.
The file has the following structure: "a_X_mytest.jpg" or "a_X_mytest.png".
The "a_" is fix and in each folder the same, and i need the "X" and the file extension.

My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in /var/www/html/MyFolder/*/
do
  dir=${dir%*/}
  find "/var/www/html/MyFolder/${dir##*/}/a_*.*" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f
done
```

That's only the beginning from my script.

There is a mistake in my script:

```
find: `/var/www/html/MyFolder/first/a_*.*': No such file or directory
find: `/var/www/html/MyFolder/sec/a_*.*': No such file or directory
find: `/var/www/html/MyFolder/test/a_*.*': No such file or directory
```

Does anybody know where the mistake is?
The next step, when the lines above are working, is to split the found files and get the two parts.

To split i would use this:

```
arrFIRST=(${IN//_/ })
echo ${arrFIRST[1]}
arrEXT=(${IN//./ })
echo ${arrEXT[1]}
```

Can anybody help me with my problem?

Comment: Why do you have a for loop in there before your find?

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr:**

Your script can be simplified to the following:

```
for file in /var/www/html/MyFolder/*/a_*.*; do
  [[ -f $file ]] || continue
  [[ "${file##*/}" =~ _(.*)_.*\.(.*)$ ]] && 
    x=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ext=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  echo "$x"
  echo "$ext"
done
```

- A **single glob (filename pattern, wildcard pattern) is sufficient in your case**, because a glob can have *multiple* wildcards *across levels of the hierarchy*: `/var/www/html/MyFolder/*/a_*.*` finds files matching `a_*.*` in any *immediate* subfolder of (`*/`) of folder `/var/www/html/MyFolder`.
  You only need `find`  to match files located on *different* levels of a subtree (but you may also need it for more complex matching needs).
- `[[ -f $file ]] || break` ensures that only *files* are considered and also effectively exits the loop if NO matches are found.
- `[[ ... =~ ... ]]` uses bash's regex-matching operator, `=~`, to extract the tokens of interest from the filename part of each matching file (`${file##*/}`).
- The results of the regex matching are stored in reserved array variable `"${BASH_REMATCH}"`, with the 1st element containing what the 1st parenthesized subexpression (`(...)` - a.k.a. capture group) captured, and so on.

  - Alternatively, you could have used `read` with an array to parse matching filenames into their components:

    ```
    IFS='_.' read -ra tokens <<<"${file##*/}"
    x="${tokens[0]}"
    ext="${tokens[@]: -1}"
    ```

---

As for **why what you tried didn't work**:

- `find` does NOT support *globs* as *filename* arguments, so it interprets `"/var/www/html/MyFolder/${dir##*/}/a_*.*"` *literally*.
- Also, you have to separate the *root folder* for your search from the *filename* pattern to look for on any level of the root folder's subtree:

  - the root folder becomes the filename argument
  - the filename pattern is passed (always quoted) via the `-name` or `-iname` (for case-insensitive matching) options
  - Ergo: `find "/var/www/html/MyFolder/${dir##*/}" -name 'a_*.*' ...`, analogous to [@konsolebox' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24655246/45375).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the needed complexity but perhaps what you want is

```
find /var/www/html/MyFolder/ -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -name 'a_*.*'
```

Thus:

```
while IFS= read -r FILE; do
    # Do something with "$FILE"...
done < <(exec find /var/www/html/MyFolder/ -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -name 'a_*.*')
```

Or

```
readarray -t FILES < <(exec find /var/www/html/MyFolder/ -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -name 'a_*.*')
for FILE in "${FILES[@]}"; do
    # Do something with "$FILE"...
done
```

Comment: I'd also suggest `-exec` to find was worth a look.

Comment: With find /var/www/html/MyFolder/ -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -name 'a_*.*' i get the right information. But when i execute the while loop i get this Exception: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: I'm genuinely curious: What's the advantage of using `exec` in the process substitution?

Comment: @user3699189 It requires bash. Make sure you run it like `bash script.sh`. @mklement0 Prevent unnecessary subshell. An original practice by me, konsolebox.

Comment: Re `exec`: That's a clever optimization - though one wishes that kind of optimization were built into the language (`bash`) itself. Have you ever _had_ to use this technique for performance reasons, or is it just preferring not to create an unnecessary subshell?

Comment: @mklement0 Yeah perhaps the shell could just exec when the only command is an external binary just like how it does some unnecessary summoning of subshell in `()`. I had to use the technique for performance reasons when summoning a process in which the returned PID of it can't just be the subshell but the process of the binary itself.