# Bash: Inline Execution returns Duplicate "Process". Why?

Tags: linux, bash

bash: 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Executing the following script:

```
# This is myscript.sh
line=$(ps aux | grep [m]yscript)  # A => returns two duplicates processes (why?)
echo "'$line'"
ps aux | grep [m]yscript          # B => returns only one
```

Output:

```
'tom   31836  0.0  0.0  17656  3132 pts/25   S+   10:33   0:00 bash myscript.sh
tom   31837  0.0  0.0  17660  1736 pts/25   S+   10:33   0:00 bash myscript.sh'
tom   31836  0.0  0.0  17660  3428 pts/25   S+   10:33   0:00 bash myscript.sh
```

Why does the inline executed `ps`-snippet (A) return two lines?

Comment: Looks like you got two scripts running: `ps -ef | grep -E "31837|31836"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Summary

This creates a subshell and hence two processes are running:

```
line=$(ps aux | grep [m]yscript)
```

This does not create a subshell.  So, `myscript.sh` has only one process running:

```
ps aux | grep [m]yscript
```

#### Demonstration

Let's modify the script slightly so that the process and subprocess PIDs are saved in the variable `line`:

```
$ cat myscript.sh 
# This is myscript.sh
line=$(ps aux | grep [m]yscript; echo $$ $BASHPID)
echo "'$line'"
ps aux | grep [m]yscript
```

In a bash script, `$$` is the PID of the script and is unchanged in subshells.  By contrast, when a subshell is entered, bash updates `$BASHPID` with the PID of the subshell.

Here is the output:

```
$ bash myscript.sh 
'john1024  30226  0.0  0.0  13280  2884 pts/22   S+   18:50   0:00 bash myscript.sh
john1024   30227  0.0  0.0  13284  1824 pts/22   S+   18:50   0:00 bash myscript.sh
30226 30227'
john1024   30226  0.0  0.0  13284  3196 pts/22   S+   18:50   0:00 bash myscript.sh
```

In this case, 30226 is the PID on the main script and 30227 is the PID of the subshell running `ps aux | grep [m]yscript`.

Answer (score 3):

- a command substitution (`$(...)`)
- *each segment* of a pipeline<sup>[1]</sup>

cause Bash to create a [*subshell*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Execution-Environment.html) (a child process created by forking the current shell process), but then Bash *optimizes away* subshells *if* they result in a *single call to an external utility*.

(What I *think* is happening in the optimization scenario is that a subshell is actually created but then instantly replaced by the external utility's process, via something like `exec`. Do let me know if you know for sure.)

Applied to your example:

- `line=$(ps aux | grep [m]yscript)` creates *3* child processes:

  - 1 subshell - the fork of your script you see as an additional match returned by `grep`.
  - 2 child processes (1 for each pipeline segment) - `ps` and `grep`; they take the place of the optimized-away subshells; their parent process is the 1 remaining subshell created by the command substitution.
- `ps aux | grep [m]yscript` creates *2* child processes (1 for each pipeline segment):

  - `ps` and `grep`; they take the place of the optimized-away subshells; their parent process is the current shell.

For an overview of the scenarios in which a subshell is created in Bash, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21338131/45375) of mine, which, however, doesn't cover the optimizing-away scenarios.

---

<sup>[1] In Bash v4.2+ you can set option `lastpipe` (off by default) in order to make the *last* pipeline segment run in the *current* shell instead of a subshell; aside from a slight efficiency gain, this allows you to declare variables in the last segment that the *current* shell can see after the pipeline exits.</sup>

Comment: I gave the check to the other answer because it was faster. But this answer is good too. Thanks

Comment: I appreciate the feedback and the up-vote, tokosh.
(I wrote this answer _after_ @John1024's, because, even though his answer is helpful and correct, I felt it lacked background information that can be helpful in related scenarios - you definitely _can_ end up with (non-ephemeral) subshells created by pipeline segments.)

Comment: Ok, I have to admit the "because faster" is a bit of a stupid argument. But, well I leave it as it is (both of you deserve it). So, +1 (can't do more) for the linked answer.