# echo wc result not right in shell script

Tags: shell, wc

this is my shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "===="
echo $1
echo "===="
ps -ef | grep -w $1 | grep -v -e "grep" 
echo "===="
echo  $(ps -ef | grep -w $1 | grep -v -e "grep" | wc -l)
echo "===="
exit 0
```

then,i execute the shell script at command line.

```
./test.sh php-fpm
```

the result is:

```
====
php-fpm
====
0   986   984   0  4:43PM ??         0:05.53 php-fpm
70   988   986   0  4:43PM ??         0:00.00 php-fpm
70   989   986   0  4:43PM ??         0:00.00 php-fpm
70   990   986   0  4:43PM ??         0:00.00 php-fpm
0   984     1   0  4:43PM ttys000    0:00.01 sudo php-fpm
501  4098   827   0 10:24AM ttys001    0:00.00 /bin/sh ./test.sh php-fpm
====
7
====
```

so,my question is:why last output is 7 not 6?

thanks.

Comment: Calling $( ... ) creates subshell, so you have one more process. In detail its explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801681/bash-inline-execution-returns-duplicate-process-why

Comment: you don't need `echo $( ...)`. Just run the `ps .... |wc -l ` pipeline without cmd-substitution. Good luck.

Comment: BTW, your program will show an incorrect result, if $1 contains *grep* as a substring, or if one of the processes displayed has the string *grep* in their arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use command

```
ps -C $1 --no-headers
```

Updated code is

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "===="
echo $1
echo "===="
ps -C $1 --no-headers
#ps -lfC $1 --no-headers
echo "===="
COUNT=$(ps -C $1 --no-headers | wc -l)
echo $COUNT
echo "===="
exit 0
```

Run

```
sh /tmp/test.sh java
```

O/P

```
====
java
====
4969 ?        00:01:00 java
6884 ?        00:00:34 java
10200 ?        00:00:18 java
====
3
====
```