# Variable from another function is not visible?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, io-redirection, scoping

I wrote the following script:

```
bar() {
        echo $(foo) >&2
        echo "bar" >&2
        echo $VARIABLE >&2
}

foo() {
        echo "foo" >&2
        VARIABLE="test"
        echo $VARIABLE >&2
}
bar
```

The output is

```
foo
test

bar
```

But if I wrote this:

```
bar() {
        foo
        echo "bar" >&2
        echo $VARIABLE >&2
}

foo() {
        echo "foo" >&2
        VARIABLE="test"
        echo $VARIABLE >&2
}
bar
```

It prints what I need:

```
foo
test
bar
test
```

The question is that I need to send `foo`'s result to `&2` yet I need the `VARIABLE` value that was set when calling to `foo`. How to do this in bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash [runs `$()` in a subshell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21338131/2877364), so the assignment to `VARIABLE` inside `$(foo)` is thrown away when the `$()` ends.  That is why the variable is not preserved.

Standard input/output/error are always available unless you change them.  Therefore, you should be able to do:

```
bar() {
        foo >&2             # <-- redirect foo's output
        echo "bar" >&2
        echo $VARIABLE >&2
}
```

**Explanation**

You can often replace uses of `echo $(something)` and similar constructions, such as `something | cat`.  In your case:

- `foo` produces output to stdout
- `$()` copies from stdout to the command line
- `echo` copies from the command line to stdout (!!)
- `>&2` redirects from stdout to stderr

The `echo $()` sequence has the net effect of copying from stdout to stdout :) , so you can just eliminate it.<sup>*</sup>

<sup>* But in other cases, you might want `echo $()`, e.g., if you are using `$()` for its side-effects, or if you are deliberately invoking a subshell to protect yourself from variables being changed by what you're executing.  However, I think those cases are probably not common.</sup>

Comment: Works, cool, thank you. But I have once more question. How about assigning `foo`'s result to a variable? `RETVAL=foo` does not call foo at all.

Comment: Sure!  That's actually a separate question :) .  `RETVAL="$(foo)"` (note the double-quotes!) will do that, if you remove the `>&2` inside `foo()`.  Try it out and post a new question if you have trouble.  Happy hacking!

Comment: By the way, please don't forget to accept answers to your questions (the checkmark) if your problem has been solved - I see from your profile that a number of your questions have well-voted answers, but no accepted answers.  Don't leave us hanging! :D

Comment: @SomeName Of course, once you do `var="$(foo)"` you'll have the same problem of the variable disappearing again.

Comment: Indeed, as @thatotherguy noted.  Think about why you're trying to do this.  Can you break down your problem in a different way so that you don't have to produce both a variable setting and a value in the same function?

Comment: @SomeName Bash is annoying in that the solution to one case is not always applicable to similar code. Just copy&paste your question but with `var=$(foo)` instead of `echo $(foo)` :P